# CI/CD deployment of Prisma ORM to Elastic Beanstalk through CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, prisma

I'm trying to deploy a simple ExpressJS app with Prisma ORM.
Here is the full project: https://github.com/oxyn/aws-codebuild/settings

I'm trying to build through Amazon CodePipeline. For build, I have selected `Ubuntu` (`aws/codebuild/standard:5.0`). For Elastic Amazon is using `Amazon Unix` as I know.

I specified binaryTargets:

```
generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["rhel-openssl-1.0.x"]
}
```

but still, I can't get data.

```
   "error": {
        "clientVersion": "3.0.2"
    },
```

This is an error that I'm getting inside of try-catch and this is log from Elastic:

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/web.stdout.log
----------------------------------------
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: /var/app/current/node_modules/.prisma/client
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: To solve this problem, add the platform "rhel-openssl-1.0.x" to the "binaryTargets" attribute in the "generator" block in the "schema.prisma" file:
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: generator client {
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: provider      = "prisma-client-js"
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: binaryTargets = ["native"]
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: }
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: Then run "prisma generate" for your changes to take effect.
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: Read more about deploying Prisma Client: https://pris.ly/d/client-generator
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: at LibraryEngine.getLibQueryEnginePath (/var/app/current/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:25285:15)
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: at async LibraryEngine.loadEngine (/var/app/current/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:24947:35)
Sep 12 04:59:50 ip-172-31-12-243 web: at async LibraryEngine.instantiateLibrary (/var/app/current/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:24913:7)
```

I'm generating Prisma in post_build section:

```
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - npm run generate
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use the Amazon Linux machine in CodeBuild and not the Ubuntu one as both have separate binary targets.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this as well. I had some problems with Amazon Machine but will try. Thanks

Comment: I tried different Images for the build but anyway it's not working.
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/9241

I opened issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I add the command "npx prisma generate" after npm install

Comment: Create .npmrc file and set `unsafe-perm=true` inside...
Or, for build environment set `NPM_USE_PRODUCTION` this environmental variable on EB with value false...
maybe both are needed. don't really remember :)